# Novel about an Earth spy on an alien planet

Tags: story-identification, novel, aliens

Plot: a spy is sent to an alien planet. He is the only Earth agent on the planet and his goal is to seed and support anti-war riots that should lead to revolt and the aliens to give up and surrender.

After a year (or years) of hard work, the agent succeeds and reaches his goal. He returns to Earth, only to discover that there is a new task of a similar nature assigned to him and he only has a few days to rest before departure.

Please help me to find this book!

Comment: In roughly which year did you read this and when do you think it might've been published? Also, do you recall anything about the cover?

Comment: My first impulse would be *[Retief](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Literature/Retief)*, but I don't know of a specific matching story.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Based on the info given, this could be [*Wasp*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?886) by Eric Frank Russell.

The titular "wasp" is a single infiltrator sent to an alien planet that is at war with Earth. The term comes from the idea that a tiny wasp attacking the driver of a car can cause a very expensive fatal accident.

> "..that wasp killed four big men and converted a large, powerful car into a heap of scrap."

The infiltrator stirs up trouble, starts rumors that ruin morale, commits selective sabotage, etc.

On the last page of the novel, the hero is sent to a new planet.

> "We're dropping you in his place. You leave tomorrow."
>
> "Hi? Tomorrow?"
>
> "Sure thing. We want you to become a wasp. Nothing wrong with that, is there?"

Comment: A great read!  Recommended.

Comment: @Martlark when I first read it as a kid, I didn't like it because it wasn't "scifi" enough for me. I felt like if you changed the names, it could be about a British infiltrator dropping into Nazi Germany. I like it better now though.